# syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\login\resources\views\pages\index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

controller.php

```
public function show($user)
{
        $post=DB::table('post')->where('user',$user)->first();
        //dd($post);
        return view('pages.index',['post'=>$post]);
}
```

route.php

```
Route::get('/post/{user}','testController@show');
```

view.php

```
 {{$post=>body}}
```

db.php

```
   sno  id  user    body
    1   1   aa  hello naresh
```

new to Laravel kindly help me to solve this error
i need to get object data body which backend

Answer (score 4):

> syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'

`=>` caused error

```
{{$post=>body}}
```

should

```
{{ $post->body }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in your blade.php file**

remove `{{$post=>body}}` and put `{{$post->body}}`

```
{{ $post->body }}
```